# Django ModelAdmin: update field without saving

Tags: python, django, modeladmin

I have an admin page that looks like this:

```
class NameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['long_name', 'short_name']
  search_fields = ['long_name','short_name']
```

In my admin page I have created a button (it is called "getname"), which after being pressed, should update the short_name field (if it's empty, otherwise leave it). However, the inserted text SHOULD NOT be saved to the database, only shown.

If the user agrees with the text, only then should he press "Save" and then it should be saved to the database.

the save_model method does of course not work, as it saves it to the database.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
  if 'getshortname' in request.POST:
    if not obj.short_name:
       obj.short_name = model_support.parse_shortname(obj.long_name)
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you just fill the field in JS?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, is your `"getname"` button on the change form view?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a form in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    update_me = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta(Object):
        model = MyModel
```

Then in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.forms import MyModelForm


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm


admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

This way, you have a field in the model that will not be saved to the database, is not required, you can update it and using the `save_model` method you can pass the value to the relevant field of your model in order to be saved to the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But I must not add any new fields to the model (it should remain untouched). Is there any way I can update the view of the admin only without touching the database at all?

Comment: @ClementFilou With the above code, the database stays intact. If you do not want extra admin fields, you could use javascript and ajax to work on the existing fields.